# What are Workflows? And how do workflows eases work of the consumer?

Tags: project-management, workflows, automation

With a little googling I could find `workflows` - which automates the business process - to meet some business needs. i.e.; All I could find is it is a piece of software which allows us to split the process into sequence of steps - and allows us to track each step - also helps us in achieving those steps.

I could find the example of HR management software which automates it's hiring process with the help of workflows. Would like to know more about how  workflows reduces the end consumer's headache.

Where do workflows fit in?

Comment: Hi queenritchie. Several things to consider. 1. Workflows are not software. It's a concept that provide some execution processes with a determined order. That being said, A. You can implement your own workflows according your needs. B. Some tools allow you to do it easier with the cost of having your workflow constrained by the tool's capabilities. 2. Asking for tools and sites is off-topic here. 3. You might be interested in [BPM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_management) if managing business process is what you need.

Comment: @Laiv Workflows are not software? Are we talking about the same thing? When I think of workflows I think of these things: [Walkoff Workflows](https://iadgov.github.io/WALKOFF/documentation.html#introduction).

Comment: i also am confused by this question

Comment: Don't you consider workflows to be an abstraction? A concept? A sequence of events or processes addressed to meet a goal? By `which automates the business process` I only understand BPMs and BPMs can model any sort of "workflow".

Comment: This is out of the scope of software engineering.

Comment: @Laiv Show me software that doesn't have abstraction. I'm thinking of automated workflows executed by an [orchestrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestration_(computing)). Not just a bunch of employees following a business plan. How is that automated?

Comment: I get your point. If any application is considered an automated workflow, could we state that any app is a BPM like [Activity](https://www.activiti.org) or [Alfresco BPM](https://www.alfresco.com/platform/process-services-bpm)? That's what I tried (unsuccessfully I see) to differenciate.

Comment: @queenritchie You've managed to confuse us. Do your workflows only deal with people? Or are you looking to automate the actual work? Keep in mind we don't do product recommendations but understanding what workflows are enough to use the right terms certainly falls within our scope. With that you'd be able to do your own research. Consider editing your question.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I would like to know where  workflows would be useful... And some example where workflows fits its exact purpose in the application...

Comment: Well that's certainly on topic. So you're not just talking about the workflow of people right?

Comment: What does it mean workflow on people? Do you mean automating the work  itself?

Comment: I really do not mean automating the work (i.e.; the process of accomplishing a step) in the workflow @CandiedOrange...

Comment: you have edited my question in much appropriate way... thanks @CandiedOrange

Comment: Workflows on people: think in any administrative procedure. Send a request and wait for aproval. The aproval should be carried by someone with the role A who has to send the request to the department B where is going to be evaluated by someone with the role C. And so on... Workflows as automated works: I want to get orders, update the stock and send the bill via email at the sametime. Do you see the difference? Both workflows, but quite different automations.

Comment: wow nice @Laiv !! I haven't realised that there are two types of workflows... you helped me to know about it.. I mean the second one `workflows as automated works` - how does workflows fit here....

Answer (score 1):

> A workflow consists of an orchestrated and repeatable pattern of business activity enabled by the systematic organization of resources into processes that transform materials, provide services, or process information. It can be depicted as a sequence of operations, declared as work of a person or group, an organization of staff, or one or more simple or complex mechanisms.
>
> [Wikipedia : Workflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workflow)

A workflow could be getting me a product that I ordered. That workflow can be a clearly defined repeatable business practice that only involves humans and paper. In which case software engineering had nothing to do with it. Or it can be completely automated so no human is involved. Or it can be a mix.

A workflow is a process:

> Process optimization, for example, can’t be achieved by simple automation. Automation is concerned with a single task – launching a web server, configuring a web server, stopping a service. Orchestration, however, is concerned with automating, if you will, the execution of a **workflow** – of a process. A provisioning process may be comprised of multiple tasks and involve multiple systems. An “application” is not just a single server, after all, it’s likely several servers – web, app and database in a traditional three-tier architecture.
>
> [devops.com - automation-versus-orchestration](https://devops.com/automation-versus-orchestration/)

If you're finding it hard to see the difference between automating tasks and orchestrating workflows of tasks you're not alone. I had the same problem. But some people just don't think of them the same way.  I've worked with these things and to me at first the difference seemed more structural and architectural than conceptual.

The structural / architectural difference I saw was tasks typically ran on one machine. Where a workflow process would weave through many devices by the ochastrating machine either remoting into the machine with the task or comunicating with a host based agent on that task running machine.

The conceptual difference is by far the important bit. There is nothing that can be fully automated that couldn't just be tasks that execute and communicate from machine to machine.

[image]

But if that's all you have there is no one single place to stand and say: "here's the whole workflow process". "Here's where we control it". Without that nothing holds the concept of the workflow. Everything is simply part of it. It's just a bunch of things talking to other things.

[image]

With an orchestrator that is aware of and controlling the workflow you can reconfigure the workflow in one place. Direct parts to swap out at will. You can even nest workflows within workflows.

Those parts may be machines, networks, people, or whole departments. It's nice to have one place to coordinate all that rather then have to configure everything one at a time.

Comment: @queenritchie please don't be so quick to choose mine as the solution. Give it a day at least. I'm hoping more answers come in because I'm still learning this stuff myself.  Might even set a bounty.

Comment: I liked the explanation given by you - and there were no other answers - so, I opted your's as the solution ... but anyways i always have option to switch to another solution ;-)

Comment: Yes but you're discouraging others who might answer.  I only have about 1 year of experience with this stuff.  Give it a chance.

Comment: @CandiedOrange you are very humble !! I haven't realised it that others might get discouraged when they have already solution for this question ... Now removed your's as solution.. Let's wait and see... So, that more people could answer... And we can choose the best one from them...

Comment: @queenritchie feel free to check the answer that you consider to be more useful for you. People who don't dare to answer because you already got the one you need, probably means that they don't have nothing signifcantly better or different to say ;-). CandiedOrange few times is wrong and whether you already got the answer or not, people will continue posting their answers. I'm sure.

Comment: Yeah sounds right !! @Laiv.. Anyways both of you added value to the question.. thanks for answering !!

Answer (score 1):

According with the comments, looks like you are asking about the possibilities of automating repetitive jobs.

Human is falible. It's not good at doing repetitive and tedius things over and over. The more times it does something the more chances it has of failing. Here is where applications, as automated works, (or workflows) fit well.

Programms are **good doing repetitive jobs**. They don't get distracted, they don't get exhaust and if they are well implemented, they don't fail. Or in the worse case, they always do the same errors :-). And on top of this, they don't have payrolls.

They also are **faster** than us, what basically reverts in the consumer benefit. Consumers are provided with a  service/product that generates  **predictive and faster responses**.

The less time we spend doing an specific job, the more time we have to go shopping or to play video games.

Finally, it **reduce the need of intermediaries**. The interaction consumer - product/service is quite more **straightforward** and **efficient**. As you know, we humans sucks in communication, so the less intermediaries the better. And **cheaper in the long run**.

That being said, I have the feeling that you are probably asking about automate business processes. Humans workflows.

As I commented, some workflows are more administrative-like and they still may require intermediaries.

Here the final result of the process is not so predictive. The process still depends on the people doing their job. Like in the public administration.

This sort of automations are known as [BPMS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_management). BPMS allow us to computerize procedures that usually would take us to do manually and in person and that get involved different persons at different places and moments. These process still require some human activity like validations, confirmations, reviews, etc.

Think how we apply for unemployement  benefits to the local administration. It require us to go to the local administration, wait for the turn, fill up a form and wait for the aproval. Then we have to be back for the renewval every month.

From the consumer point of view is a huge waste of time. From the guy/gal at the local administration office is an insane amount of work and papers.

Computerizing this workflow, the local administration allows citizens to apply for the benefits from home. Or from wherever they are. They also can check out the request's status (in process, waiting for aproval, aproved, rejected). **Traceability** we call it.

From the consumer point of view, automate workflows are seen as a **time and energy savings**. From the provider point of view, are seen as **cost-cutting and reliable** tools. They can make faster a business process that traditionally would take days or weeks to get done. The provider no longer need to send a messenger half way across the world to get the form X and wait for the best.

From everybody point of view, they allow us to focus on what matter. Anything but repetitive and tedius jobs.